# Organizing rails controllers within namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a fairly simple question about the code organization of rails controllers:

If we have an app store platform (i.e. Google Play) which consists of Developers (They create/upload the apps), Admins (Review and approve the apps) and Users (Who consume the apps via the store).

The developers do everything through the developers platform, so it would make sense to have a developers namespace to group related items. The same logic would seem to make sense for the admin, give them an admin panel under an admin namespace.

Now here's the question - I have two namespaces, `Admin` and `Developer` - if, a developer can change an app's state from :draft to :pending (for review) and the admin can change the state from pending to :approved/:rejected, where is the recommended place to store apps_controller.rb?

There seems to be three ways to handle this and I'm not quite sure which is the most 'correct', either for practical reasons or conventional reasons.

The three options I can think of are:

1) In both the `Admin` & `Developer` namespace (and populate the store from developer::apps)?

2) Only in the `Developers` namespace

3) The apps_controller should not live in either namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worries, you are in OO world.

Two designs:

1. Make a general AppsController but no routing to it. Admin and Developer's apps controllers will inherit this, and overwrite when necessary.
2. Make a module and get it included in Admin's AppsController and Developer's, overwrite when   necessary.

It's hard to say which is better without detailed use case, though I would prefer #1 generally.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, #1 sounds like a sound approach. However, the Developers::AppsController currently inherits from Developer::BaseController (in order to inherit authorization settings etc) - in this case would it be best to go with #2, or is there a workaround I could do?

Comment: Yes, then #2 will do in this case.